# Realign UV Map for texturing

Tags: uv

I am trying to make a texture for this cup, but when I unwrap it, the parts are scattered. Is there a way to easily align them? This is my first time using blender so all help is appreciated! [image]

Comment: you should first use Mark Seam, then, when you unwrap > a simple Unwrap, not Smart UV Project

Comment: It looks like you have many unconnected polygons? try to Edit Mode  -> select all and press W -> Remove Doubles and unwrap it again.